# Insert string at the beginning of each line with python

Tags: python

First sorry my english is bad..
Today i want a help from you dears..
I need a python code who can add same word at the beginning of each line ..
Anyone can help me?
Good Bye

Comment: please read [ask] and provide more details/context/code/whatever

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like below.

```
with open("infile.txt", "r") as input:
    lines = input.readlines()

myword = "same word"   

for line in lines:
    print("{} {}".format(myword, line))

 # or

with open("outfile.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        outfile.write("{} {}".format(myword, line)
```

Please take the time to try to construct you questions better.

Comment: No it's not like that .. so i have a websites list like : facebook.com / google.com and its in lines .. facebook in 1 line and google in 2nd line so no problem in the lines so i have more that 10 m of websites i can't modify it with notpad i want a script to add http:// at the beginning of each line.. i hope it's clear now